# Mapbox GL JS : Displaying lat, lon location

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I have implemented a LAT LON readout of the cursor location in my webpage by following the example at [This Mapbox GL JS Tutorial](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mouse-position/)

However, the returned values come in as something like :

```
{"lng:-74.949147382928,"lat":40.43829220439884}
```

You can see that in their example. Is there a way to only return the LAT and LON values? I would like something like :

```
-74.949147382928, 40.43829220439884
```

I am not very great with javascript, but I tried experimenting to use *substring* to modify the output like follows, but I am unable to do so. Surely there is an easier way? The code I tried is below, which was only a test just to see if I could theoretically do it. But using substring in this fashion doesnt seem to work. I am looking for any way to just return the LAT and LON values only, to be clear.

Failed Code :

```
topleftmapbox.on('mousemove', function (e) {
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
        JSON.stringify(e.lngLat.substring(6,17)); // attempting to substring out just the values
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `JSON.stringify()` with `event.lngLat`, you can just access the **properties** `lng` & `lat` of the `lngLat` object:

```
const info = document.getElementById('info');
info.textContent = `${e.lngLat.lng} ${e.lngLat.lat}`;
```

The example uses `textContent` instead of `innerHtml` and [JavaScript template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (backticks) to format the string to display.